# how do i write to a file when I am getting unicode encode error

Tags: web-scraping, unicode

Please see attached i am web scraping using bs4 and getting the attached error. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code where you open your file with the following:

```
with open("firefly2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
   file.write(transcript)
```

Hope it helps!